# How to create an executable JAR of Next.js app?

Tags: javascript, next.js, executable

I would like to know how to make my Next.js file work on every computer without having to reinstall all my modules.

Basically, I have my folder, nextjs-node, containing the following folders:

```
components 
lib
public
node_modules
page style
package.json
```

I'd like to know if there is something I could do to create an icon on which I can just click to launch my website without have to go to the folder in my terminal and type `npm run dev` .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If it is fixed, you can provide an answer on how it was fixed. And in the future, tell us more about "how to create icons". Vague statements make it difficult to reproduce ... And this solution must already be in our database ... Google is also a solution.
This is now believed to be a programming error. Please report the detailed error.

Answer (score 0):

As a heads up, stack overflow is more for asking specific questions rather than general project approaches, as a result this will most likely be flagged eventually.

However to answer your question:

So next just creates a framework for websites which means that what you want to do isn't quite possible however there are a couple of options here:

1. You want to have an executable that launches your platform as an electron app. An example could be done with: https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron
2. You can always just host this as a website, and users can use shortcuts to just link over to the site in a web browser.
3. You can make your site a progressive web app where the user can save your site locally (however you will still need to do option 2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure I completely understood your options. In fact, my app is already created in NextJS and I'd just like for a user to be able to launch it for an executable

Comment: Then you're going to want to look into electron.